# Create listener in the IBM WebSphere MQ v5.3

Tags: ibm-mq

How do I create the listener in WebSphere MQ version 5.3? I have used the `runmqsc` command and enter into console and try to execute this command:

```
DEFINE LISTENER (name) TRPTYPE(TCP) PORT(99990)
```

But is throwing and `AMQ8426` error and saying:

> Valid commands are DEFINE AUTHINFO,DEFINE CHANNEL,
>   DEFINE PROCESS, DEFINE NAMELIST,DEFINE QALIAS, DEFINE QLOCAL,DEFINE
>   QMODE,DEFINE QREMOTE

Answer (score 9):

> How do i create the listener in the MQ version 5.3?

You don't.  That component wasn't available in v5.3, a version of MQ that was out of service in 2007.  In fact, it has been out of service for so long, that IBM has removed the online Infocenter for it.  However, you can still find the individual [MQ v5.3 manuals online](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/wmq/library/library53.html).  In particular, the [Intercommunication](http://publibfp.dhe.ibm.com/epubs/html/csqzae09/csqzae09tfrm.htm) manual [section on receiving on TCP](http://publibfp.dhe.ibm.com/epubs/html/csqzae09/csqzae092p.htm#Header_381) explains that with this version you will need either to use `inetd` or the `runmqlsr` program.

Of course since v5.3 has been out of service for 8 years on most platforms, the more important advice here is *use a modern version*.  IBM has provided a license that allows people to run an unrestricted MQ server install on their laptop or PC at no charge.  The product/license name is [IBM MQ Advanced For Developers](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/ibm-mq-advanced-for-developers).

Note that while it is important for individuals to move to a modern version of MQ, it is even more so for the companies using MQ for business purposes.  In the 8 years (as of this writing) since v5.3 was retired, there have been many security-relevant fixes, none of which were maintained in the 5.3 code base. Obviously, that goes for all the performance improvements, bug fixes and enhancements as well.

There are almost no legitimate reasons for anyone to still be working with MQ v5.3 (which I am intentionally not enumerating here) but if you actually are facing one of them and are stuck at that version, use the `runmqlsr` program and launch it in your start script.

But the correct answer for virtually EVERYONE else reading this is *do NOT keep using MQ v5.3*.